# Что возвращает Clickable Point?

Tags: c#

Какую именно точку возвращает свойство Clickable Point? И будет ли результат одинаковым каждый раз, если мы вызовем это свойство n раз?

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? В статье на MSDN вроде бы все объяснено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Свойство возвращает произвольную точку - просто точку, по которой можно кликнуть.
2. Постоянство результата не предопределено: в зависимости от реализации точка может возвращаться одна и та же, либо каждый раз разная.